# Special lower bound on minimum singular value

Tags: linear-algebra, singular-values, hermitian-matrices

We know that any square matrix $M$ could be written in the form $H_1 + iH_2$ for some Hermitian operators $H_1$ and $H_2$. Denote the smallest singular value of a matrix by $\sigma_m(.)$. Can we lower bound the value $\sigma_m(H_1+iH_2)$? (For example, like $\sigma_m(H_1+iH_2) \geq \sqrt{\sigma_m(H_1)^2 + \sigma_m(H_2)^2}$?)

Answer (score -1):

Are you familiar Weyl's Theorem (see Thm 4 [here](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Efoucart/TeachingFiles/F12/M504Lect5.pdf))?
By reproving it using the [Courant-Fischer Theorem for singular values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_principle_for_singular_values), you get that for Hermitian matrices $A, B \in M_m$ with singular values $\sigma_1(A) \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_m(A)$ and $\sigma_1(B) \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_m(B)$,
$$\sigma_k(A) + \sigma_m(A) \leq \sigma_k(A+B) \leq \sigma_k(A) + \sigma_1(A) \,,$$
for all $k = 1, \dots, m \,.$

Applying this to your problem, we get
$$\sigma_m(M) = \sigma_m(H_1 + i H_2) \geq \sigma_m(H_1) + \sigma_m(iH_2) = |\lambda_m(H_1)| + |\lambda_m(H_2)| \,,$$
where the last equality follows since [the singular values of a Hermitian matrix are the absolute values of the eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886599/singular-value-of-a-hermitian-matrix-are-the-absolute-values-of-eigenvalues-of-a).

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I don't think your argument is correct. For your set of inequalities, set $A=-B$ and you will get that zero is greater than a non-negative number (which with appropriate choice of $A$, becomes strictly positive, like $A=-B=\mathbb{I}$).